# Cannot run apache airflow after fresh install, python import error

Tags: python, flask, airflow, werkzeug

after a fresh install using `pip install apache-airflow`, any attempts to run airflow end with a python import error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/\*/env/bin/airflow", line 26, in <module> from airflow.bin.cli import CLIFactory
File "/Users/\*/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 70, in <module> from airflow.www.app import (cached_app, create_app)
File "/Users/\*/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/www/app.py", line 26, in <module> from flask_wtf.csrf import CSRFProtect
File "/Users/\*/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_wtf/__init__.py", line 17, in <module> from .recaptcha import \*
File "/Users/\*/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_wtf/recaptcha/__init__.py", line 2, in <module> from .fields import \*
File "/Users/\*/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_wtf/recaptcha/fields.py", line 3, in <module> from . import widgets
File "/Users/\*/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_wtf/recaptcha/widgets.py", line 5, in <module> from werkzeug import url_encode
ImportError: cannot import name 'url_encode' from 'werkzeug' (/Users/*/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/__init__.py)
```

Comment: looks like i got this same problem today and was wondering about it coz no major change in my code that i think will throw this type of error

Comment: I installed airflow on an instance three days before and it was working fine. Similar way I installed it on another instance... it throws the same error..

Answer (score 23):

It seemed to be a versioning error, the newer versions of the werkzeug package no longer have the url_encode that airflow is looking for, installing a lower version (`pip install werkzeug==0.16.0`) resolved the issue and airflow now runs without failing.

Comment: Yep using werkzeug 1.0 (included with Flask) gave me this same error, moving back to 0.16.0 fixed it

Comment: Nice one @Jacob! If you want to get potential patch updates, use instead `pip install werkzeug==0.16.*`...

Comment: Great @Jacob your answer saved my lot of time else I will be ending up debugging the same .

Answer (score 2):

We have fixed it in Airflow 1.10.9, please install the latest version:

```
pip install -U apache-airflow
```

or pin Werkzeug by running `pip install werkzeug<1.0`