# Getting Error while installing apache-airflow

Tags: python, airflow

I am getting above error when i try airflow -version and airflow initdb

````
  File "/home/ravi/sandbox/bin/airflow", line 26, in <module>
    from airflow.bin.cli import CLIFactory
  File "/home/ravi/sandbox/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 70, in <module>
    from airflow.www.app import (cached_app, create_app)
  File "/home/ravi/sandbox/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/www/app.py", line 37, in <module>
    from airflow.www.blueprints import routes
  File "/home/ravi/sandbox/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/www/blueprints.py", line 25, in <module>
    from airflow.www import utils as wwwutils
  File "/home/ravi/sandbox/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/www/utils.py", line 39, in <module>
    from flask_admin.model import filters
  File "/home/ravi/sandbox/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_admin/model/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .base import BaseModelView
  File "/home/ravi/sandbox/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_admin/model/base.py", line 8, in <module>
    from werkzeug import secure_filename
ImportError: cannot import name 'secure_filename' ```
````

Comment: Try installing a lower version of werkzeug (pip install werkzeug==0.16.0) as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60104484/cannot-run-apache-airflow-after-fresh-install-python-import-error

Answer (score 45, accepted):

With this, it worked, thanks:

```
pip install werkzeug==0.16.0

DB: sqlite:////home/centos/airflow/airflow.db

[2020-02-07 12:02:02,523] {db.py:368} INFO - Creating tables
```

Comment: cool! what is the logic behind that though?

Comment: @khanna https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-python/issues/256